# How to detect a Trusted Web Activity (TWA) in Android Apps

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I'm working on a script that analyzes the AndroidManifest.xml of decompiled apps and detects if they contain a TWA or not.

Is there a better approach for detecting a TWA than analyzing the AndroidManifest? I'm currently checking if the below activity is defined in the manifest or not, but almost all the apps from my dataset gave negative results;

```
<activity android:name="com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity">
```

Answer (score 0):

Apps generated by Bubblewrap (via the CLI, PWA Builder, etc) will have a `twa_generator` [meta-tag](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/blob/ad218b54404189de89bbe12d85091e536d18ad99/packages/core/template_project/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L54-L56). Checking `com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity` won't work for current Bubblewrap generated apps since each application will have its [own LauncherActivity implementation](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/bubblewrap/blob/ad218b54404189de89bbe12d85091e536d18ad99/packages/core/template_project/app/src/main/java/LauncherActivity.java).

Checking for `com.google.androidbrowserhelper.trusted.LauncherActivity` **or** if the `twa-generator` may work better.

Comment: Thank you Andre, I'll try this approach.  (PS: I was just watching your Google I/O'19 session on TWAs when I got this notification..! : )

Comment: Is it a better idea to detect TWAs with more parameters. I found few manifests in the Google Chrome/android-browser-helper repo which will fail to be detected [https://github.com/GoogleChrome/android-browser-helper/tree/main/demos] 

[1.] The twa-firebase-analytics and twa-offline-first have custom implementation but its manifest includes ***androidbrowserhelper.trusted.FocusActivity*** and ***support.customtabs.trusted.DEFAULT_URL***

[2.] The twa-custom-launcher includes ***androidbrowserhelper.launchtwa.LaunchTwaActivity***

Comment: So in that case, is it a better idea to also include checks for **androidbrowserhelper.trusted**, **androidbrowserhelper.launchtwa** and **support.customtabs.trusted**?